# How to create a thicker bottom of a bottle

Tags: edit-mode, glass

I'm quite new to Blender, I've done few things but none of them was so complex regarding modeling of the object in the edit mode as the one I need to seek advice on: so I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_acSZh_BG8 and I don't understand how is the author of the video making the bottom of the glass bottle thicker than the rest of the bottle (it's around 1:30). He applies solidify modifier and then seems to just manipulate the faces and edges of the bottle without manipulating the "outer layer" of the bottom (created by solidify).
I know there are some similar questions already (like here [How do I make a glass with a thicker bottom than top?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199228/how-do-i-make-a-glass-with-a-thicker-bottom-than-top)), but I'd like to know how it could be done in this specific way, like in the video. The man just seems to grab and move it like that: [image] [image]

And I don't understand what the hell... (also he's going really fast for me)
I think I've done everything like him, which is:

1. roughly model it from a cylinder
2. add subdivision surface mod. (2)
3. apply layer of subdivision
4. apply solidify

- I added another subdivision surface which he does not do

Thank you so much for any advice!

Comment: I think he has just moved up the inside of the bottom part, most likely after the solidify was applied.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand, he applies the Solidify modifier, so now the inner faces exist for real, he selects the faces at the center, then extends the selection with Ctrl +, and moves up (GZ)

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem with my object – it doesn't work for me, because when i try it, it always moves together with the outside part

Comment: maybe proportional editing is still "on". You may see a grey circle around the selection if this is the case.

Comment: If the tutorial is too fast you can slow it down to 1/4 speed by clicking on the gear wheel Settings icon on the bottom status bar  then clicking the Playback Speed entry and checking '.25'. As @lemon says you've probably left Proportional Editing turned on.

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The only clue he's given us is the 'Select More' panel. This implies he's selected the center vertex of the inner base, and Ctrl  Numpad+  expanded the selection from there, before GZ moving it up. He's got the room to do it without prop. editing. You could switch on prop. Editing with 'Connected Only ' checked  if you wanted to ease some of the inner wall up, too, to make room. Personally, I would go with the linked method and weight the _Solidify_ instead, to keep it alive as long as possible, for tweaking geometry at  provisional render-time.

Comment: I agree with @lemon here, when your outer part moves although you have only selected the inner part, then _Proportional Editing_ is enabled. Either this or you still have a _Solidify_ modifier on the object.

Answer (score 2):

> ...then add a solidify modifier to add thickness, apply it and make
> any last adjustments such as rounding the shape at the top of the
> bottle and I like to make glass at the base slightly thicker.

So the adjustments are not described in the tutorial, but solidify modifier is definitely applied first. It appears the tutorial assumes you have knowledge of modelling and selection functions. If you don't, you should choose other tutorials that would give you that knowledge first.

He is using [loop selection tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) and [transform operators](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/transform/index.html), as well as [Loop Cut and Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/loopcut_slide.html#loop-cut-and-slide), [Select More/Less](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/more_less.html#select-more-less) and numerous other functions, that's in my view a bit too much to describe in detail in a single answer. Tutorials will be better suited to cover everything faster, the manual is also a great resource. You should probably go through all these menus in edit mode and make sure you know what each function does try and play around with all of them for a couple of days before following that tutorial:

[image]